# Line Login in Android Not working getting Socket TimeOut Exception

Tags: java, android

I have implemented line login by following the documentation of line Console. created a channel ID and implemented the code according to the development website.
https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/android-sdk/integrate-line-login/#handling-login-result.

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

final TextView loginButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try{
            // App-to-app login
            Intent loginIntent = LineLoginApi.getLoginIntent(
                view.getContext(),
                Constants.CHANNEL_ID,
                new LineAuthenticationParams.Builder()
                        .scopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE))
                        // .nonce("<a randomly-generated string>") // nonce can be used to improve security
                        .build());
            startActivityForResult(loginIntent, REQUEST_CODE);

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

When I click on line login button the above code is calling as per the docs.

Expected: it should go to the app and fetch user profile

Result : When user clicks on login button after some time getting timeout exception like - LineApiError{httpResponseCode=-1, message='java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to api.line.me/218.248.112.60 (port 443) from /192.168.1.34 (port 45462) after 90000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by changing the system DNS to 8.8.8.8.
Default DNS is not working for Line.